# Pymongo find using $in with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

The folowing expression works fine, returning the values that match the values list:

```
[...].find({"FieldName":{"$in":["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]}})
```

But i have the list of values in a list object, like this:

```
valuesList = list()
valuesList.append("Value1")
valuesList.append("Value2")
valuesList.append("Value3")
```

But using the list object, a get no results:

```
[...].find({"FieldName":{"$in":[valuesList]}})
```

I Have also tried expanding the list in a formated string, like this:

```
strList = ', '.join(valuesList)
[...].find({"FieldName":{"$in":[strList]}})
```

but also, no results.

Note: If i force the list to have only one value, it works. Only when multiple values are suplied, the result is blank.

Any ideas on how to use "$in" in pymongo with a list of values in a list object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the fact that you have a list inside of a list.

Instead of:

`[...].find({"FieldName":{"$in":[valuesList]}})`

Try:

`[...].find({"FieldName":{"$in":valuesList}})`